# Using setState to set all state of react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a page where I'm gonna take the whole state of the page and set it with some localstorage so I need to use SetState but not using some property like sane people do

Sane people

```
this.setState({ 
  stateProperty:someValue
})
```

Me (what I want to achieve)

```
this.setState({
  this.state: {someValues}
})
```

Comment: why cant you just get everything from localstorage and set on the page? why do you need to do this.state inside of setState?

Comment: your initialState and localStorage have save object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can actually call a this.state={something} on constructor

This did the trick

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

          if ( typeof store.get([store.get("auth").ID]) === "undefined") {
              store.set([store.get("auth").ID], { localStorageData: {} });
          }

          this.state = {
              ...bla bla bla
          }

          this.state=Object.assign({}, this.state, this.state.localstore ) 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. Sorry, you can't. You've accepted yourself that is sane people do like, but why are you trying to go insane code?

It's better to maintain for localStorage data with specified state:

```
state = {
  storeData: {} // or, [], or whatever your stored data type
}
componentDidMount() {
  const storeData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store-data'))
  this.setState({
     storeData
  })
}
```

Some people might suggest you to initialize localStorage data directly in the constructor. But I'm against it because I don't like to cause some side effect to the component.

PS: There' no side effect actually using `localStorage` data in the constructor. I have just suggested to use `componentDidMount` hook because you might need to call some api which will call to load the `localStorage` data and that time you might have some side effect. To ignore this, use `componentDidMount` hook because it's an asynchronous function which runs in background.

Answer (score 1):

For set/get state from localStorage use this:

```
localStorage.setItem('store-state',JSON.stringify(this.state));
const storeState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store-state'));
this.setState(storeState);
```

With this code you able to store/reload your state from localStorage. notice, in setState no need to create any objects({}).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
const updateState = window.localStorage.getItem('whatever');
let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
newState = updateState;
this.setState({newState});
```

Hope it works.

Comment: it seems like you're resetting the value of `newState` in L3 to be the value of localstorage rather than the value created by your `object.assign()`. Why?

Comment: I thought it was your goal hehehe maybe misunderstood this line "im gonna take the whole state of the page and set it with some localstorage", could you explain a little better what would like to do?

Comment: I think he means the second line of your code is useless

Comment: Well i actually discover that you can call this.satet= something directly right after the set state of constructor, but i also use the object.assing to make the merge